# DoesNotExist at /register/ User matching query does not exist

Tags: django, database, django-models, production

I have some issues I never had to deal with in the development phase. When the users posts some actions, I sometimes get the following error.

[Image of error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOqhi.png)

What really frustrates me is that the project works fine in the local environment and furthermore, the matching query object DOES NOT exist in the Database.
And also my password1 and password2 fields does not exits in database table even i created in form.py.

Comment: Can you share your form, view and model?

Comment: See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that others can understand your problem and help you better

Comment: You're trying to get user object by username but it does not exists that's why it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question properly. So I just write a sample project for you.

urls.py

```
path('login/', user_views.CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='user-login'),
path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
path('register/', user_views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='user-register'),
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    profile_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email",)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
         
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['pattern'] = '[a-zA-Z]+'
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
    
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['pattern'] = '[a-zA-Z]+'
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
    
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['profile_image'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
    
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'First Name'
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Last Name'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter your username'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter your email'
    
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter your password'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter confirm password'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['data-v-equal'] = '#id_password1'
```

view.py

```
class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


class RegisterView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
    success_url = '/login'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        base = form.save()
        UserProfile.objects.create(
          user=base,
          profile_image=form.cleaned_data.get('profile_image')
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```